# How to compute the remaining free space or width of div?

Tags: angular

I am looking for a way to compute the remaining width of a div after adding inner spans dynamically

[image]

```
GetWidth() {
    let txt = divElement;
    console.log(event.target.closest('span').scrollWidth);
  }
```

HTML

```
<div
class="wrapper"
style="border: 1px solid gray; height: auto; width: 230px"
>
<span
*ngFor="let item of pgFilters[i].value; let i = index"
class="cont"
>
{{ item }}
</span>
<input (keyup.enter)="add($event, i)" class="inputx" />
</div>
```

Style

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inputx {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

TS

```
add(event: any, index: number): void {
    const value = (event.target.value || '').trim();
    if (value) {
      this.pgFilters[index].value.push(value);
      event.target.value = '';
}
```

I have added the complete code.. here i am trying to implement chips control on my own..

Comment: maybe if you share the reason,why you need it, the community could help you to find better decision?

Comment: sure, in the remaining width i am putting a text input, as user will type the text and presses' enter so that the text entered will add as span (simplar to chips)

Comment: sounds like you problem can be resolved with just pure css. no javascript is required

Comment: can you please direct me to some code

Comment: I think just `<div class="wrapper" (display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap)><span *ngFor...>...</span><input flex-grow:1>` should work or will almost work as required. it is not a valid code, I was just trying to describe what styles on each element are main ones for reaching the goal here

Comment: I tried the code and it doesn't work the way i expect. I updated the HTML and Style code in my question

Comment: Are you trying to make a Chip input? if that's the case... all you need is to set your `span`'s width to `fit-content` and apply the container style as `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap`. That should work.

Comment: yes chips control, Can you please check the code i posted.. i posted everything and still it doesn't seems to work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

It gets the rectangular coordinates of the last `<span>` using `yourSpan.getBoundingClientRect()`.. so the `right` property of the object returned describes the distance from the left side of the div... So if you know the parent `div`'s width.. you can just subtract that `right` property value from the `div`'s width.

```js
function GetRemainingWidth(){
  var div = document.getElementById("div1");
  var w = div.offsetWidth - div.children[div.children.length - 1].getBoundingClientRect().right;
  return `${w}px`
}

console.log(GetRemainingWidth());
```

```html
<div id="div1">
I weas here
  <span>I am Great!</span> <span>Are you?</span>
</div>
```

For this code to work... Please do the following in your html. Put the `<span>` elements into a separate wrapper from the input.

```
<div class="wrapper" style="border: 1px solid gray; height: auto; width: 230px">
  <div class="filter-elements" id="filter-elements">
    <span *ngFor="let item of pgFilters[i].value; let i = index"
        class="cont"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </span>
  </div>
  <input (keyup.enter)="add($event, i)" class="inputx" />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you Mosia.. how do i convert this to px?

Comment: remember that value is in `px`. so you can just append `.px` on it.

Comment: but the value i am getting is way greater than the actual Div width

Comment: Really?  Please run the snippet. I'm getting a value that makes sense.

Comment: ah ok.. i think i changed something and got it.. but it works fine in first line, when i goes to second line, it has to consider only the spans present in second line

Comment: @SamK I don't think that would be necessary. The best approach is to force the first line's spans to cover the entire with before you let them wrap... That way you always know that the remaining with will always come from the last child(span child).

Comment: If you can't implement that, let me know I can do something for you. But what I provided here is something to work with considering that only 1 line will have a remaining space relative to the div's width.

Comment: Not sure why, when try this code, i keep getting this kind of a value -1594.203125px

Comment: Can you atleast post your html? Include it in your question.

Comment: I posted the HTML code in my question

Comment: Ahhh I see. Your code will be calculating using `<input>` as the last child. So it always uses the input's coodinates. I didn't realize that the input was inside the same container with the `span` filter elements.

Comment: Still the same value i am getting after putting span elements under div

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure of what you're doing on your side since the code in the question above doesn't show much. Do you mind sharing your TS as well because I see you're using Angular... Please share your Typescript code so that I can check it...

Comment: I aleady shared my TS as well

Comment: No, I don't see any typescript code where you applied my code above.

Comment: If you become too slow on this, I am gonna have to move on. Show the code where you applied `GetRemainingWidth()` in your code. Because my code works perfectly for what you're trying to achieve. Looks like you can't seem to get it right on your side...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244743/discussion-between-mosia-thabo-and-sam-k).

Comment: I finally figured it out.. thanks for all your patience @Mosia. I had to take the relative position since my element was no on left side of the page

Comment: well done @SamK I'm happy you finally made it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parentElement like this

```
function remaining(){
let txt = divElement;
let parent=txt.parentElement;
let remain=parent.offsetWidth-txt.offsetWidth}
```

If you may have multi child in this element you can do this

```
function remaining(){
    let txt = divElement;
    let parent=txt.parentElement;
Let child=parentElement.children;
 let remain=parent.offsetWidth;
child.foreach(element=>{
remain-=element.offsetWidth;
}
conole.log(remain);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives the same width everytime

Comment: I have updated the code for working if you have multi child give it a shot now